# Missing MIDI events when sending data from Android via a USB OTG cable to a synth

Tags: android, events, media, midi

I'm writing an Android app that sends tunes to a synth, using the standard android.media.midi interface. I'm using a M-AUDIO cable to connect from the phone's USB socket with an OTG cable.
While the app works fine most of the time, I'm finding that some (probably about 1 in 1000) MIDI events do not get sent resulting in missing notes, and most annoyingly, notes stuck on after a tune has finished.
The same cable works fine from a laptop running a similar application.

Comment: Specifically what MIDI adapter are you using?  A lot of the M-Audio gear was held over from the MIDIMan days, and did not use class-compliant MIDI.  Android supports it, but it may be using a different driver.  Have you tried a different MIDI adapter?

Comment: Brad: thanks for your reply. I'm using the UNO cable I purchased a couple of weeks' ago. I also have a Roland UM-ONE Mk2 cable and I get the same issue with that. I'm not certain about class compliance so I'll put in a question to M-Audio to clarify that.

Comment: The Uno is what I had in mind.  They may have changed it over the years... at least the one I bought ~20 years ago was not strictly class-compliant.  In any case, since you're having the same trouble with another adapter, I'm not sure what to suggest.  You've tried other MIDI applications and see the same missing messages?  Also, I had a controller keyboard once where if you played notes too fast, it would drop messages and result in stuck notes.  Just trying to rule out all possibilities.

Comment: Hi Brad, I'm trying to find another app that definitely uses android.media.midi and that can play MIDI files - do you know of one?

Comment: You might try something that uses WebMIDI.  Chrome on Android supports MIDI... might be more options there.

Comment: @canaryowl I also have similar problem , did you solved it somehow ?

Comment: Hi Renetik. No I didn't really resolve this, so I resorted to ensuring my code sends all notes off at the end of a sequence, and whenever possible during the sequence! Not nice, but I was putting too much time into looking for a full solution.